# Is it possible to use a service principal to authenticate against dynamics crm online?

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-active-directory

I tried the following:

```
            AuthenticationParameters ap = await AuthenticationParameters.CreateFromResourceUrlAsync(
                        new Uri($"{CrmServiceUrl}/api/data/"));

            var _authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(ap.Authority);

            AuthenticationResult result = await _authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ap.Resource, new ClientCredential(_clientID,secret));

            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);

            var req = await client.GetAsync($"{CrmServiceUrl}/api/data/v8.1/accounts?$select=name&$top=3");
            Console.WriteLine(await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

but is getting

```
HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied
```

clientid and secret is a azure ad service principal.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not done this myself but I'm going to guess probably not. To access data inside CRM you need to have a user account inside CRM - that's how the security model of CRM is applied after authentication.

I would suggest looking here [Authenticate users in Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328497.aspx), which describes all the ways you can authenticate with CRM.

Comment: ended up adding an extra user and then use the resource owner flow against azure AD to get token for that user, then everything worked. But no way to use a service principal